# Get specific value from JSON array after comparison using PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

I want to get specific value once key is matched from JSON array object

Input:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "19A7A3C4",
        "displayName": "somename",
        "tags": [
            {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "apple",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "orange",
                "value": "20"
            },
            {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "grapes",
                "value": "30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "111111",
        "displayName": "somename",
        "tags": [
            {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "cat",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
                "context": "CONTEXTLESS",
                "key": "cat",
                "value": "20"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the value of tag where key matches to cat and value matches to 10, I am using below query but getting whole object

```
$content = Get-Content -Raw -Path "data.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$content | Where-Object{ $_.tags.key -eq "cat" -and $_.tags.value -eq "10"}
```

**Desired Output: 10**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mathias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079673/7571258) already shows a clean way to solve the problem.

A similar approach is using the [intrinsic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members#foreach-and-where) `.Where{}`:

```
$tagValues = $content.tags.Where{ $_.key -eq "cat" -and $_.value -eq "10" }.value
```

`$content.tags` employs [member enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#member-enumeration) to collect all `tags` properties into an array. `.Where{}` filters array elements similar to `Where-Object`. Lastly `.value` uses member enumeration again to collect the filtered tag values into an array.

Intrinsic methods like `.Where{}` are supposed to be faster than pipeline commands because they don't involve the overhead of the pipeline machinery.

---

If you want to keep your original query, you have to deal with nested properties.

Use [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#grouping-operator--) `()` and dot notation to extract a given property:

```
$tagValues = ($content | Where-Object{ $_.tags.key -eq "cat" -and $_.tags.value -eq "10"}).tags.value
```

An alternative is `Select-Object` with parameter `-ExpandProperty` (alias `-Expand`), but it doesn't work as straightforward for nested properties ([yet](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14633)):

```
$tagValues = $content | Where-Object{ $_.tags.key -eq "cat" -and $_.tags.value -eq "10"} |
    Select-Object -Expand tags | Select-Object -Expand value
```

A more straightforward alternative is `ForEach-Object`:

```
$tagValues = $content | Where-Object{ $_.tags.key -eq "cat" -and $_.tags.value -eq "10"} |
    ForEach-Object { $_.tags.value }
```

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate all tags, then use `ForEach-Object` to grab just the `value` property of any match:

```
$content.tags | Where-Object { $_.key -eq "cat" -and $_.value -eq "10"} |ForEach-Object -MemberName value
```